# What's the best practice to store complex data structure in core data on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, core-data

I have a complex data structure along with some other data fields that used for query that need to save with core data for future use. I am thinking of serialize the complex data structure into JSON string and store as one string field in core data entities instead of create an entity with many properties. This complex data structure is purely saved for future use, there is no query on any properties required, however I do need to query on the other data fields so I am thinking of use core data.

I am wondering is this (store as JSON string) the best practice or there is a better solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, no, that would not be the best solution.  If you don't want to store the object with a data model you create then Core Data will give you very little benefit.  You'll basically have a bunch of opaque objects that you won't be able to distinguish until you deserialize its json string.  If that's sufficient for your needs, then I'd recommend just archiving the objects to disk and skipping the overhead of Core Data.

Comment: In my scenario I have a complex data structure and a number of other properties which I plan to store in core data.  This is basically a task queue, I have task meta data which is a complex data structure, and a bunch of other fields, e.g. owner, priority, time, jobid..., I will need the query on those field, but only the task job thread need the data in the task meta data.

Comment: Ahh, I did not realize that by the verbiage of your question.  I still would advise against this, as it feels like a misuse of Core Data (if you've already got a data model, why quit now and cheat with this data?).  BUT....I don't see this causing any technical problems, as long as you treat it as it is, which is basically a binary field that you can't search, sort, or filter on.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, yes it works, I am looking for "best practice". If I don't core data, what do you suggest to use?  I was considering archive or serialize the data to disk however it's not ideal for queries.

Comment: If this is just opaque data that you don't need to examine the data itself, then I'd say archive it to disk, store the path on your Core Data object.  If you would need to deserialize these objects in order to figure out which one you're looking for, then I'd say bite the bullet and just add it to your data model and store it related to your other Core Data entities.  What's the pain point you're trying to avoid by storing them as raw json?

Comment: Thanks  @Paul.  This data structure contains nested dictionary and array of data, if I create them as entities, I might end up create multiple related entities, either store the data in or read the data out would be quite a few code... not neat. JSON or XML seemed to be the best format to store this sort of data. I am kind of not like the idea of store file path of archives...

Comment: I'm not sure what other solution to suggest.  If you've got data with an unpredictable schema, then archiving the combination of dictionaries and arrays seems like a good option to me.  Is there any specific reason you don't like that approach?  I'm not sure what else to suggest.